# How do we update facts in clara rules? (clojure)

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, rules, rule-engine

```
(ns clara.rules.test
  (:require [clara.rules :refer :all]))

(defrecord Users [#^ints user-ids])
(defrecord UserData [user-id dob age]

(defrule rule-1
 [?ud <- UserData (> age 20)]
 [?u <- Users]
 =>
 ((retract! ?u)
  (insert! (->Users (conj (:user-ids ?u) (:user-id ?ud)))))

(defrule rule-2
 [?ud <- UserData (some-condition)]
 [?u <- Users]
 =>
 ((retract! ?u)
  (insert! (->Users (conj (:user-ids ?u) (:user-id ?ud)))))

(defn run-rules
  [user-data]
  (let [res (-> (mk-session 'clara.rules.test)
                (insert (->UserData (:user-id user-data) (:dob user-data) (:age user-data))
                        (->Users []))
                (fire-rules))])
```

I'm trying to append user-id to `Users` defrecord or update the list. I'm inserting an empty list as Users fact to the session. The action for the rule that I wrote won't work, But I want to do something similar.

I would like to know if there's a way to update the existing fact or delete and insert a new updated fact on rhs of the rule.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `retract!` on the right hand side of a rule [to retract a fact](http://www.clara-rules.org/apidocs/0.9.0/clojure/clara.rules.html#var-retract.21).

(In your code you used `retract` which does not modify the current session, only returns a new one.)

Comment: Hi,@erdos. Sorry, I used`retract!` only it was a typo.I have updated that. Still its not inserting the new updated fact.
The `:fact->explanations` is `nil` when I inspected the session.

Comment: Also, the `retract` itself cannot be used on RHS.